# QGIS - Unable to save after mergin attribute - (SpatiaLite - Triggers)

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, trigger

I'm working with SpatiaLite layers, and I'm currently encountering a problem when I use the tool: « Merge attributes of selected entities ».

I use several triggers that are not the cause of the problem. *However, there are other triggers in place that might be the source of my issue, such as:*

```
    CREATE TRIGGER "ggi_HABITATS_POLY_geometry" BEFORE INSERT ON "HABITATS_POLY"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'HABITATS_POLY.geometry violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
WHERE (SELECT geometry_type FROM geometry_columns
WHERE Lower(f_table_name) = Lower('HABITATS_POLY') AND Lower(f_geometry_column) = Lower('geometry')
AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."geometry", geometry_type, srid) = 1) IS NULL;
END

CREATE TRIGGER "ggu_HABITATS_POLY_geometry" BEFORE UPDATE OF "geometry" ON "HABITATS_POLY"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'HABITATS_POLY.geometry violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]')
WHERE (SELECT geometry_type FROM geometry_columns
WHERE Lower(f_table_name) = Lower('HABITATS_POLY') AND Lower(f_geometry_column) = Lower('geometry')
AND GeometryConstraints(NEW."geometry", geometry_type, srid) = 1) IS NULL;
END
```

EDIT : These two triggers are not the source of the issue.

My project involves a column named "pkuid" with auto-incremented values for added or updated features. When using the "Merge Attributes" tool, the "pkuid" values do not update.
I suspect this could trigger the "unique values constraint".

I made a trigger to update "pkuid" before the update, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Here is the error message :

> 2024-01-16T11:54:11     WARNING    Erreur SQLite : UNIQUE constraint
> failed: HABITATS_POLY.pkuid
> SQL: UPDATE "habitats_poly" SET "pkuid"=64921, [...all the columns...] WHERE "pkuid"=65108

Maybe I can edit these constraints, but I didn't write them, I don't want to totally break the project.

Comment: I will try by creating a sequence CREATE SEQUENCE pkuid_sequence START WITH (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(pkuid), 0) + 1 FROM HABITATS_POLY); and generate my table again with pkuid following the new sequence : CREATE TABLE HABITATS_POLY (
    pkuid INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('pkuid_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
-- and my other columns 
);

Comment: It is not possible apparently.